# is it possible to create a user forum in communities?

Tags: community, chatter

I am just getting started in creating my first community and I am looking to see if it would be possible to create a user forum to where my end users can set up forum topic groups and then ask question and provide feed back on those topics. Is there a standard feature for this? Or could Chatter server for what im looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The out Of box templates like Napili does that for you .At very high level Napili template provides

- Featured Topics
- Navigational Topics

Also chatter comes integrated with ability to ask question .Answer questions ,Like those answers and feeds .Select as best answer and a community manager can do analytics out of same .

You can tag discussions and questions with Topics .Check this [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ob3pJ3mMS6M)

You need to enable chatter answers and Topics .